# Redirect URL with query string to homepage

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I can't figure out how to make users visiting my website using links like: `mysite.com/?ref=XXXXXXX` see the homepage instead of a completely blank page. I tried using htaccess but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is how my *.htaccess* file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=(.+)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^index.php http://mysite.com/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What server-side language are you using to process query strings and what is the default document name (e.g., index.php)?

Comment: I'm using apache, and it's name is index.php

Comment: (I realise you've solved this, but...) If you are accessing `mysite.com/?ref=XXXXXXX` then your `RewriteRule ^index.php`... is never going to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to a *.htaccess* file in your document root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure you have the `mod_rewrite` module installed.

Comment: Still getting a blank page.

Comment: Try this then:
`RewriteRule ^index.php http://mysite.com/? [L,R=301]`
Also be sure to check that `mod_rewrite` is installed and enabled in your _httpd.conf_

Comment: I have mod_rewrite installed and enabled. But this still didn't work :/

Comment: Be sure to completely clear the cache in your browser. I assume the  home page is not blank, correct?

Comment: Still blank, I tried clearing cache too.

Comment: I'll assume that your homepage isn't blank...will give it some thought. Perhaps someone else will have an idea.

Comment: Yes, the homepage isn't blank. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you mind adding a URL to your site? I'll delete it afterwards. Also check your server logs each time you hit the URL to see if it provides some clues (like maybe an error). It might be a good idea to copy your .htaccess file into the question as well.

Comment: Seems the URL with query string is returning a 200 OK response with no content. I'd check your logs. Also, posting your .htaccess file might help.

Comment: I fixed it and I have no idea how I did it! Just kept changing some things in my code and after a while I checked the website and it was working!!
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries...glad you got it fixed. Was going to suggest a simpler directive to strip the query string, as contained in the third example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/onlyvalidation/page/strip-unwanted-query-string-apache).